# Redirect User on Login based on role WP 3 - Multi-Site

Tags: redirect

I need to have users land on a specific admin page based on user role in WP 3.0 multi-site enabled.  I found this

```
function fb_redirect_2() {

    if ( preg_match('#wp-admin/?(index.php)?$#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ) {
        if ( function_exists('admin_url') ) {
            wp_redirect( admin_url('edit-comments.php') );
        } else {
            wp_redirect( get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-admin/' . 'edit-comments.php' );
        }
    }
}
if ( is_admin() )
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'fb_redirect_2' );
```

And changed

```
if ( is admin() )
```

to

```
if ( current_user_can('edit_posts') )
```

but this isn't working...

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Did you confirm this code as working before you tweaked it?

Answer (score 2):

you need to populate the

```
current_user_can('')
```

function before using it
using

```
  get_currentuserinfo();
```

so try this code:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'fb_redirect_2' );

function fb_redirect_2(){
    get_currentuserinfo();
    if ( current_user_can('edit_posts')){
    //redirect here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This worked great.  Obviously I know enough PHP to be dangerous;-) I am also finding this works for WP standard roles, however on the custom roles defined in functions.php it totally ignores the whole thing??? Anyone have any idea - I'm off to search...

Comment: did you define the capabilities of the custom roles?

Comment: yes.  in the functions.php file  It seems to be dependent on what happens first - the role declaration or the redirect rule?

Comment: Actually if user tries to log in at main domain, the rule is ignored because of the role specification for that site... works fine when they log in at maindomain.com/theirsite.  I am now looking for a way to have the user re-directed to their member blog backend... if any body has an suggestions I would gladly accept!  Meanwhile searching...